# hold view for 3 seconds then push for another view

Tags: iphone

I want to hold view for 3 seconds then view will be switch,What will i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(changeMyView) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
```

will call the method `[self changeMyView]` after a delay of three seconds.  You can also use `NSTimer` to do the same thing.  `sleep(3)` will pause everything for three seconds, but it will pause *everything*, so it's probably not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sleep(3)` before pushing the new view controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) class to schedule whatever activity you wish. NSTimer does not block the UI thread so application remains responsive. But you need to be careful in handling the user interaction during this time.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the NSTimer class. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Timers.html